# Dataframe Explode and map with correct data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe Like this

```
Bad      ActionID   ActionText     Status
[3,2,1]  [2,16,16]  ['a','','c']  yes
[1,2]    [1,10]     ['yes','no']  nil
```

and I want the output data frame to be exploded and mapped with the correct position of elements in the rows. so the output will be like.

```
Bad   ActionID   ActionText  Status
3       2          'a'       "yes"
2       16         ''        "yes"
1       16         'c'       "yes"
1       1          'yes'     "nil"
2       10         'no'      "nil"
```

please help.

I have removed the date column just for more clearity. of original data

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#if necessary convert string repr to lists
#import ast
#df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].applymap(ast.literal_eval)

df = pd.concat([df[x].explode() for x in df], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Bad ActionID ActionText Status
0   3        2          a    yes
1   2       16               yes
2   1       16          c    yes
3   1        1        yes    nil
4   2       10         no    nil
```

Comment: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
i am getting this error

Comment: @R.singh - There is always match length of lists for each row?

Comment: yes, the length of each column elements like date , actionId ,action text will always be same as bad column length .

Comment: Hi @jezrael there can be another column 'status' after Date which will be just a string and can be common

Comment: could you please help.

Comment: @R.singh - Sure, can you change data for this column? Also error means some data related problem, data are confidental?

Comment: Data is confidential., can you please be more specific what you requrie for more clarification

Comment: @R.singh - Unfortunately very hard thing - create data sample with same error...

Comment: can you please check ?

Comment: @R.singh - Do you think changed data? Answer was edited - only first part `df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].applymap(ast.literal_eval)`, second working correct. But one idea - how working if use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution?

Comment: @R.singh - Yes, unfortunately data related problem.